# How do I select certain siblings via CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <script></script>
  <script></script>

  <ul class="cars">
      <li class="headline">My Cars</li>
      <li>Ferrari</li>
      <li>Hummer</li>
  </ul>

  <noscript></noscript>
  <script></script>
  <script></script>

  <ul class="cars">
      <li class="headline">My Cars</li>
      <li>Volvo</li>
      <li>Caddilac</li>
   </ul>

  <noscript></noscript>
  <script></script>
  <script></script>

  <ul> etc....

</div>
```

Question: How can I hide ALL the `<li class="headline">My Cars</li>` elements, except the first one, using only CSS?

I asked a slightly similiar question yesterday which the answer for worked fine, but the scenario has changed which caused further problems. I'm in a position where I have only control over the CSS so please do not suggest using JavaScript or modifying the HTML.

It's those damned `<script>` and `<noscript>` elements which causes the solution from yesterday to totally fail.

For browser compatibility I would appreciate if the solution did NOT use CSS3.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are all those `<script>` tags there? I know, I know, you said "don't suggest modifying the HTML", but having all those `<script>`s is representative of poor design.

Comment: Yeah I know. And agree. The script tags has something to do with ads being "inserted" there.... and sadly I can't do anything about that.

Comment: Is there definitely not a `<noscript>` element for the first set of elements?

Comment: Yes it is definitely so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not feasible using CSS2 unless you could modify your HTML somehow, e.g. to include a `first` class to your first `ul`. Without being able to touch your HTML, there isn't a CSS2 selector I can come up with.

But if the answer to both of these questions is yes:

1. Are all your `li.headline`s only going to be in `ul` elements?
2. Is your `div.wrapper` only going to contain either `script`, `noscript` or `ul` elements as children?

Then it's easy with CSS3 selectors:

```
.wrapper > ul:first-of-type ~ ul li.headline {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I put the CSS3 solution there as a last ditch effort. At least it works for browsers that support it anyway.

Comment: The answer to both your question is yes. And the solution works fine since I'm using FF4. However, do you know a well updated site which states which browsers supports the ~ selector/operator?

Comment: @Foad Farkhondeh: Most general-use browsers support it, including IE7+.

Comment: @Foad Farkhondeh: It's `:first-of-type` that you have to worry about. That's IE9+ only.

Answer (score 3):

With your *exact* HTML structure (not having a `<noscript>` above the first set of `<script>` elements) this will work:

```
.wrapper > noscript + script + script + .cars > .headline {
    display: none
}
```

I very much dislike it though, because it's too fragile. I'd rather use JavaScript than that abomination.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/davT8/

This will work in IE7+ and modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
li.headline {
    display: none;
}
```

It is compatible in all standard browsers (see compatibility here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html )

Comment: Wouldn't it be the other way round just to display the first one?

Comment: @BoltClock -- Missed that apparently. Yeah CSS alone isn't gonna do it unless you have access to the html to change the classes around.

Comment: @blankabout Yes, it doesn't really matter if I hide all except first or only display the first one.